# Are unix pipe (|) and pipe we create using "pipe(int pipefd[2])" in c the same?

Tags: c, unix, pipe

Are unix pipe (|) that pipelines the output of a process to another and pipe we create using "pipe(int pipefd[2])" in c used for inter process communication the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not quite the same in the sense calling `pipe(2)` is not enough to implement the equivalent function of shell's `|`.

[`pipe(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) creates two file descriptor (read end and write end). But you need to do more than that to implement `|` functionality.

Typical sequence of creating a pipe goes like this:

1) Create a read end and a write end using `pipe(2)`.

2) Create a child process using `fork()`.

3) Parent and child processes duplicate the file descriptors using `dup2()`.

4) Both processes, each closes one end of the pipe (the one end of pipe that each process don't use).

5) One writes to the pipe and other reads from the pipe.

Consider simple example to demonstrate this is. In this you pass a filename as argument and the parent process "greps" the file that's `cat` by the child.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int pipefd[2];
  int pid;

  char *cat_args[] = {"cat", argv[1], NULL};
  char *grep_args[] = {"grep", "search_word", NULL};

  pipe(pipefd);
  pid = fork();

  if (pid != 0)
    {
      dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
      close(pipefd[1]);
      execvp("grep", grep_args);
    }
  else
    {
      dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
      close(pipefd[0]);
      execvp("cat", cat_args);
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to doing

```
cat file | grep search_word
```

on the shell.

Comment: why are duplicates created? can't we write and read data without duplicating?

Comment: It's not strictly necessary (`dup2()`) in all parent-child process communication. You parent and child could communicate directly too. For example, parent can `write(2)` into the the write end of the pipe and child can `read(2)` from the read end.

Comment: @PsAkshay because the executed grep and cat only read/write from 0 and 1, not the pipefd's.

Answer (score 6):

Shell pipe `|` is implemented using `pipe(2)` and `dup2(2)` system calls.

See [*Unix Pipes*](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~mamrak/CIS762/pipes_lab_notes.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `pipe(2)` syscall used by shells for piping with the `|` operator

`|` is the implementation of shell, it intenally uses the `pipe()` syscall.